# Download Dialog Box

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, download

How to change Design of Download Dialog Box in C#.Net? 
How can I slove this problem?
(or)
How to hide Current Source File Path in Download Dialog Box?

Comment: what is download dialog box wrt ie? if its want i think it is, you **cannot do that** changing browser defaults is / should be impossible

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Your question isn't very clear, but I am assuming you mean the download dialog that Internet Explorer displays when downloading a file.

The control is defined by the browser creators and is hard coded. No browser that I am aware of gives any type of access to this control or any way to change it.